# Execute Command on the Docker Container Running on Azure Container Instance using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, docker, owasp, azure-cli, azure-container-instances

I wanted to use OWASP ZAP in my Azure DevOps pipelines and wanted to use the Docker Image that is available. Also wanted to run the docker container on demand. Found an article on [Microsoft DevBlog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/azure-devops-pipelines-leveraging-owasp-zap-in-the-release-pipeline/) that addresses this use case. When I tried to replicate that I ran into an issue. When i tried to execute the following command using Azure CLI i came across this error message.

```
az container exec --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $aciInstanceName --exec-command "zap-baseline.py -t https://example.com -x OWASP-ZAP-Report.xml"
```

> rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed:
>   container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"zap-baseline.py -t https://example.com -x OWASP-ZAP-Report.xml\":
>   stat zap-baseline.py -t https://example.com -x OWASP-ZAP-Report.xm l:
>   no such file or directory"

When i did some digging around, I found that `az container exec` [command does not support using arguments on the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-exec#restrictions).

Then I created a custom docker image based off of owasp/zap2docker-stable image where I added a bash script that basically runs the same command and tried to call the bash file from Azure CLI

```
az container exec --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $aciInstanceName --exec-command "execute-zap-baseline-test.sh"
```

But then i get the following error message.

> rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed:
>   container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec format
>   error"

Would really appreciate some help resolving this issue. How can i execute the scan on the OWASP ZAP docker container running on Azure Container Instances

Comment: Any more questions? Does the solution solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Why don't you leave any response to someone who wants to help you solve the problem?!!

Comment: @CharlesXu You need to chill out. I did not find time to try your answer yet. I will and accept the answer if its correct. Moving from ACI to AKS is not an option for me, i don't want to have a whole AKS cluster just to run this. i want this to be on demand. Also, I know about the ACI limitation on the docs, its there on the question as well. I want do see why the exact solution that is described in the DevBlog does not work for me.